# Select value instead of text from option + XML DOM

Tags: php, symfony, select, xmldocument, xmldom

I'm trying to get the values of a select list with the name = Reeks that you can find on this page: http://www.volleyvvb.be/?page_id=1083. The select list looks like this:

```
<select class="vvb_tekst_middelkl" name="Reeks" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="%" selected="">ALLE REEKSEN</option>
    <option value="Liga A H">ETHIAS VOLLEY LEAGUE</option>
    <option value="Liga B H">LIGA B HEREN</option>
    <option value="Ere D">LIGA A DAMES</option>
    ...
</select>
```

This is how I get the select list:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.volleyvvb.be/?page_id=1083");

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$crawler = $crawler->filter("select[name='Reeks']");
foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    foreach($domElement->childNodes as $child) {
        $value = $child->nodeValue;
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

What I see now is all the lines between the `<option></option>` like `ALLE REEKSEN, ETHIAS VOLLEY LEAGUE`. But I would also like the values like Liga A H, ... How can I select them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code

```
<?php
require_once("resources/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.volleyvvb.be/?page_id=1083");
$doc = str_get_html($html);

$select = $doc->find("select[name='Reeks']");
foreach ($select as $domElement) {
    $child = $domElement->find('option');
    foreach($child as $option) {
        echo $option->getAttribute('value')."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

gives me the output you requested.

```
Liga A H
Liga B H
Ere D
...
```

An equivalent for the DomCrawler Component would be

```
$value = $child->nodeValue; // LIGA B HEREN, ...
$attribute = $child->attr('value'); // Liga B H, ...
```

For further details take a look at the [Documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Comment: Thanks! I used your second solution like this: $child->getAttribute('value');

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  [each method for crawler](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_each) and [attr mehtod for crawler](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_attr)

try this :

```
$crawler->filter("select[name='Reeks']")->each(function ($node, $i) {
    echo $node->text();       -> // to print the value of html
    echo $node->attr('value'); -> // to print the value of value attrbuite
});
```